# What library to import for Geocoding with Bing Maps in VB?

Tags: vb.net, geolocation, bing-maps, geocode

I'm trying to implement the demo Reverse Geocoding here: in VB http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966828.aspx

What library can I import, or "add a reference to in VB" so I don't get the following errors:

Type 'GeocodeService.Credentials' is not defined.

Type 'GeocodeService.Location' is not defined.

Type 'GeocodeService.GeocodeServiceClient' is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up the table of contents on the left hand side of the page, you'll see that page is a subtopic of the Bing Maps SOAP Services. Click on that link to get a list of lots of articles about the service, including a link to SOAP Service Addresses at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966738.aspx, which will give you the endpoints for all the services.

For this example, GeocodeService should be a reference to

http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc